# Given $n>8$, let $a_n=\sqrt{n}$ and $b_n=\sqrt{n+1}$. Which is greater: $a^b$ or $b^a$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

> Given $n>8$, let $a_n=\sqrt{n}$ and $b_n=\sqrt{n+1}$. Which is greater: $a^b$ or $b^a$?

I don't know if my proof is correct. So $a^b = e^{b\ln a}$ and $b^a = e^{a\ln b}$. We know $a^b\geq b^a\Leftrightarrow b\ln a\ge a\ln b\Leftrightarrow \frac{\ln a}{a}\ge \frac{\ln b}{b}$  Set $f(x)=\frac{\ln x}{x}.$ Then $f'(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{\ln x}{x^2}$ which is negative for $x>e$. $b>a>e$ so  $f(x)$ is decreasing on $[a,b]$. Thus $f(b)>f(a)$ so $a^b > b^a$.

Comment: Technically, $\max\{a^b,b^a\}$ is equal whichever of the two _numbers_ is larger. It is not an arrow pointing left or right depending on which side is larger. Since $a^b$ and $b^a$ are very different numbers from $\frac{\ln a}{a}$ and $\frac{\ln b}{b}$, there isn't actually equality where you have equality.

Comment: @Arthur is my edited answer "technically" acceptable?

Comment: Yes, that's better. But at this stage, why not just write $a^b\geq b^a\iff \frac{\ln a}{a}\geq \frac{\ln b}{b}$?

Comment: oh right it seemed like what i wrote was not very concise

Comment: As I said, i wish there was a nice way of writing "Whichever side is larger in _this_ inequality, the same one is larger in _that_ inequality". Kindof like $\pm$, just for $\leq$ and $\geq$ rather than $+$ and $-$. Something like $\gtreqless$. But that just looks messy. I'm not sure it's really helpful. We'll just have to make do with writing _one_ of the inequality directions, and $\iff$ between the inequalities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof is correct. It's precisely the same method I would use to solve it. The fact that the function is decreasing for $x>e$ and the fact that $e<\sqrt{8}<a$ is indeed very useful.